# Camel and CXF Producer Endpoint

Tags: web-services, soap, cxf, apache-camel

I'm trying to send a SOAP message to an external SOAP service. What I need to do is wrap an xml string with the SOAP message and add some SOAP headers for authentication purposes. Right now I'm using:

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="someEndpoint" wsdl="someWSDL.wsdl"
                 address="http://someAddress:9999/service.asmx"/>

<camelContext>
    <route>
        <from uri="vm-someChannel">
        <to uri="cxf:bean:someEndpoint?dataFormat=PAYLOAD"/>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

This works but I also need to include soap headers as well. The payload mode only sends a soap envelope with a body. I've tried using an interceptor to inject headers but its getting ignored.

Is it possible to have a soap header section with payload mode? If not, what is the easiest way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can get and set SOAP headers in payload mode, more info here - http://camel.apache.org/cxf.html#CXF-HowtogetandsetSOAPheadersinPAYLOADmode

You could do this in a bean or processor before sending to the CXF bean endpoint

EDIT: Adding Code example

```
@Override 
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

    Message out = exchange.getOut();
    if (out.getHeader(Header.HEADER_LIST) == null) {
        out.setHeader(Header.HEADER_LIST, new ArrayList<SoapHeader>());
    }

    List<SoapHeader> headers = CastUtils.cast((List<?>)out.getHeader(Header.HEADER_LIST));

    try {

        SoapHeader header = new SoapHeader(new QName("Header Name"), "Header Value");
        header.setDirection(Direction.DIRECTION_OUT);
        header.setMustUnderstand(true);
        soapHeaders.add(header);     

    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Docs for SoapHeader - [Here](https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/binding/soap/SoapHeader.html#SoapHeader%28javax.xml.namespace.QName,%20java.lang.Object%29)

You will need to properly construct your Header using a QName

Comment: These examples seem to show how to access SOAP headers once a SOAP message is received. Am I sending just plain XML to the soap endpoint hoping the endpoint will translate it into a SOAP envelope. It doesn't seem like the examples are showing this. Am I just missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: @user3511727 Edited my answer with a code snippet that should create a new SoapHeader.

Comment: Thank you for the reply and code posting.

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be working either. I am getting this error message:

    org.apache.camel.InvalidPayloadException: No body available of type: org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfPayload on: Message: [Body is null]. Caused by: No type converter available to convert from type: null to the required type: org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfPayload with value null.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: That means the body of the message is null, are you sure you have a body in the message? Try logging it before sending to the cxf endpoint using this code: `<log message="Here's the body: ${body}"/>`

Comment: I had to end up creating the soap message myself and just sending it to the endpoint due to some time constraints. Thank you for your help though!